# i try to double click a .jar file but it will say "what do you want to open this with"

Tags: windows-8.1

I dont get this but i am trying to run it, how do i run this please help

Comment: this really frustrastes me, please reply

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you.

Right Click on your jar file ->  Properties -> Change -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

If you have installed java somewhere else, please use that path. For more information use this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

Comment: Erm... where are the program files?

Comment: nvm... i found out

Comment: I cannot find the java folder

Comment: Did you install Java in your PC?

Comment: Erm... windows installed it on my computer when it was setting up, so... no?

Comment: Windows installed?

Comment: No, i had to install it, also i found out, thx for the help!!! :)

Comment: Its not running. i try to double click it and then nothing happens, and when i try to run it from the command prompt it pops up an error